# Not able to throw error from response filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, filter

I am trying to implement a filter to modify the response of my api response. I also have some filters to modify my request, which is working fine.

Below is my Filter

```
public class ResponseFilter implements Filter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ResponseFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        httpResponse.sendError(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Error while extract....");
    }

}
```

Filter Registration Bean

```
@Configuration
public class FilterBean {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(FilterBean.class);
    
    @Value("${filter.urls}")
    private String filterUrls;

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<ResponseFilter> responseFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<ResponseFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        LOGGER.debug("Inside responseFilter Bin....*********");
        registrationBean.setFilter(new ResponseFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns(filterUrls.split(","));

        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

below is the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:456) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at com.example.filter.ResponseFilter.doFilter(ResponseFilter.java:41) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
```

**Can someone please help me, in intercepting a response, before it reaches the invoker.**

Comment: What happens if you move the `sendError()` call to before the `chain.doFilter()`?

Comment: It will work as a request filter, and execute before my controller gets executed. I want to intercept the response

Comment: Its better to use a `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` extending controller class for this. Annotate this class with `@ControllerAdvice`  and write a method that handles the exception you want to intercept. This method must be annotated with `@ExceptionHandler(YourException.class)`. For instance: `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    private ResponseEntity handleAndLogRuntimeExceptions(Exception exception){`.  You could also create a custom exception that you throw in case of a regular exception. In this custom exception you then wrap any data that you want to return as a response.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, calling `doFilter` means that the `ServletRequest` and the `ServletResponse` are passed to the next filter (in the `FilterChain` object). So when you try sendError, you get `Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed` (you have already committed your response via `doFilter`).

So if you're looking to pass the request to the controller and return a `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST`, to my knowledge you can't do that.